# DirectoryNotFoundException: could not find a part of the path '/var/task/...'

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, lambda, aws-lambda

I have a .net project (lambda in .net core 3.1) -  and I published this project on AWS Lambda, that is, I created a Function.

I have an email sending structure as follows:

```
 public async Task FunctionHandler(CloudWatchEvent<object> input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            SendEmail();
            context.Logger.Log($"Testing sending mail {input.Time}");
        }

        public bool SendEmail()
        {
            try
            {                
                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

                //Sender
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("...");

                //Mail construction
                mailMessage.CC.Add("...");
                mailMessage.Subject = "Test";
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.Body = CreateBody();

                //Configuration smtp - Outlook
                SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com", Convert.ToInt32("587"));
                smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("...", "...");
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

                //Mail sending
                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private string CreateBody()
        {
            string body = string.Empty;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("HTML/TemplateEmail.html")) 
            {
                body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            };

            return body;
        }
```

The html template is in another file within the same project:

[image]

I published this whole BTG.SignHUB.Schedule project in AWS Lambda and created a Function referring to this project, when running this local code, it works normally, however, when another AWS service uses this Function, it returns the following error in log:

`Could not find a part of the path '/var/task/HTML/TemplateEmail.html'.: DirectoryNotFoundException`

Is there any configuration I need to do to see the template in this /var/task directory?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the HTML file exists and is in the correct location in the Lambda environment?

Comment: How do I check my lambda environment code?

Comment: `when another AWS service` - which one? is this ECS?

Comment: It is a function in AWS Lambda

Comment: You could embed the file into your application's compiled image and reference it from there. See https://josef.codes/using-embedded-files-in-dotnet-core/ for example